# Regex to find particular endings

Tags: javascript, regex

If I use a new regex object like this:

```
for(i=0; i < aray.length; i++){
    searchTerm = new RegExp("\\b" + aray[i] + "(e\\b)", "gi");
    word = testText.match(searchTerm);
    if(word){
        found.push(word);
    }
}
```

The resulting array "found" contains {one,three,piece}.
However if I change that to:

```
for(i=0; i < aray.length; i++){
    searchTerm = new RegExp("\\b" + aray[i] + "(e\\b)");
    word = testText.match(searchTerm, "gi");
    if(word){
        found.push(word);
    }
}
```

The resulting array "found" contains {one,e,three,e,piece,e}. Where are the additional e's coming from?

Also what would be the best way to search for words ending in "e" or "es" or "et"?

Comment: The additional 'e's are coming from the line `found.push(word)`. Essentially, match returns an array of matches not a boolean. Use the `test` method to get a boolean.

Comment: @Pete you are right. Read more about [JavaScript String match() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp)

Answer (score 0):

> Where are the additional e's coming from?

That is due to your capturing group `"(e\\b)"`

Use this regex to avoid it:

```
searchTerm = new RegExp("\\b" + aray[i] + "e\\b");
```

Answer (score 0):

The "best" method is subjective, but this is what I would do.

If you are only supporting IE9 and above, then I would highly recommend using the [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.

```
var myArray = [ 'bananna', 'doge', 'doges', 'doget', 'dogets' ]

var results = myArray.filter(function(item) {
   return (/(e|es|et)$/i.test(item));
});

console.log(results);
```

The regular expression `(e|es|et)$` translates roughly into find any 'e' or 'es' or 'et' at the end of the string. So this will match any word ending in 'e', 'es', or 'et'. See [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MrRampage/vK247/) for demo.

Comment: `return /(e|es|et)$/i.test( item );`

Comment: @zyklus Good catch, no need for the 'g' flag as there is only 1 ending. :)